# Extract exact value from column based on value in another table

Tags: sql-server

I'm stuck at a keyword/text parsing problem and hoping someone could help me here.
I have a config table which has the below structure

```
Value
----
LXW
CFG
BBK
OBK
```

I have another table Details which has the below structure

```
  Details
  -------
  ID |  Note                             |  Date
  ------------------------------------------------
   1  | LXW was a beautiful warrior       | 2020-07-01
   -----------------------------------------------------
   2  | A great leader CFG was            | 2019-10-30
   -----------------------------------------------------
   3  | BBK deserved better               | 2020-09-17
   -----------------------------------------------------
```

From the table details, I need to extract only the below output based on terms in Value table

```
 Desired Output
 ------
 
 ID | FinalValue
 ----------------
 1  |  LXW
 ---------------
 2  |  CFG
 -----------------
 3  |  BBK
```

I tried charindex, contains etc but couldn't figure out how to extract only the Terms found in Value table.

Any input on how i can proceed will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you, therefore, not just after this?

```sql
SELECT YT.[Value]
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.Details D
              WHERE D.Note LIKE '%' + YT.[Value] + '%');
```

... Based on the new goalposts...

```sql
SELECT YT.[Value], D.ID
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN dbo.Details D ON D.Note LIKE '%' + YT.[Value] + '%';
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I thought of it, but I would want to get ID as well. I will update the desired output accordingly. Sorry about that.

Comment: Changing the expected results *after* receiving answers is pretty frowned @Lucky . I have, however, given a second answer.